# How do I configure an ASP.NET web page to use wsHttpBinding when querying CRM Online?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, dynamics-crm-online, wshttpbinding

How do I configure an ASP.NET web form to send requests via `wsHttpBinding` rather than `basicHttpBinding` when querying CRM Online?

As a bit of background this is a pretty basic ASPX page hosted locally in IIS 8.5.
The page is meant to connect to CRM Online and pull some data.
**Edit: This app is authenticated via Azure AD which is why it uses a client ID and key. I want to shy away from using connection strings and domain credentials unless this is unavoidable.**

I think I've got the authentication to CRM correct but when I run a query I receive the error below:

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'..

I think this is because I haven't specified a binding in `web.config` so my page is sending everything via `basicHttpBinding` and the CRM Online interface is expecting `wsHttpBinding`.

I've tried using the example at the bottom of [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731299(v=vs.110).aspx) (and variations thereof) but it makes no difference.

Here's the code for connecting to CRM in case it makes a difference. Obviously I've obscured the real configuration details.

```
// CONFIGURE OAUTH
var tenantName = "mycompany.onmicrosoft.com";
var authString = string.Format(@"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}",tenantName);
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authString, false);
var clientId = "123ab123-123a-1a23-abcd-1a2345612345";
var key = "nStgfrdk0oyaC1P5+/FQ4wGn4fRgUTr8HTKejytf0bv=";
var clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, key);
var resource = "https://myinstance.crm4.dynamics.com";

// ACQUIRE THE AUTH TOKEN
var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred);

// CREATE THE CONNECTION TO CRM
var orgService = new OrganizationWebProxyClient(
    new Uri("https://dev.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc"), true)
    {
        HeaderToken = authResult.AccessToken,
        SdkClientVersion = "8.1.0"
    };

// RUNNING THIS QUERY CAUSES THE ERROR
var contacts = orgService.RetrieveMultiple(new QueryExpression
{
    EntityName = "contact",
    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("firstname", "lastname")
})
.Entities
.Select(item => item.ToEntity<Contact>());
```

Here's the stack trace in case it's of use:

> [WebException: The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'..]
>      System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +1740
>      System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout) +75
>
> [ProtocolException: Content Type text/xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service https://dev.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.]
>      System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +14350190
>      System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +388
>      Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService.RetrieveMultiple(QueryBase query) +0
>      Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.WebServiceClient.WebProxyClient`1.ExecuteAction(Func`1 action) +51
>      Quote_Robot_Demo.d__4.MoveNext() +887
>      System.Runtime.CompilerServices.<>c.b__6_0(Object state) +56
>      System.Web.Util.SynchronizationHelper.SafeWrapCallback(Action action) +110
>      System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +13847892
>      System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61
>      System.Web.Util.WithinCancellableCallbackTaskAwaiter.GetResult() +32
>      System.Web.UI.d__523.MoveNext() +7970

Edit: Once I added the service reference I got this in my web.config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="CustomBinding_IDiscoveryService">
      <textMessageEncoding />
      <httpsTransport />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://dev.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc"
    binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_IDiscoveryService"
    contract="CRMService.IDiscoveryService" name="CustomBinding_IDiscoveryService" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695810(v=crm.7).aspx

Comment: I should have specified that this app is authenticated via Azure AD so it uses a unique client ID and key provided by Azure to sign in. The SDK examples use connection strings but they require Windows credentials and I don't want to do that. I'll edit my question to be more specific about this.

Comment: CRM SDK is not just for on-premise installations, it also supports CRM online version, so no matter how your app is hosted, you can use the SDK to connect to a CRM instance, no matter how it is hosted. Also, SDK in the background does exactly what you are trying to achieve, it handles all the communication channels for you.

Comment: I know the SDK is also for CRM Online, I'm using SDK classes in the code above... I don't think I understand what you mean by saying the SDK does everything for me, it clearly doesn't default to the correct SOAP version (1.2) which is why I get the error.

Comment: Please post the <system.serviceModel> section of your web.config.

Comment: @ClintB That's the problem, by default there isn't one generated by Visual Studio. There's a default one at the bottom of this article that I've tried to adapt but it makes no difference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731299(v=vs.110).aspx. I can't find any other good examples of what this section should look like to follow correctly.

Comment: When you add a service reference and supply the url to the web service the IDE will generate a <system.serviceModel> section.  Have you tried adding the service reference that way?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise that was necessary. Have added the relevant section to my question. I'm not sure how to change this to specify `wsHttpBinding` at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I now have some other issues I did discover how to alter the binding.
You can add the organization service as a service reference to your project as I did and then assign the binding like this:

```
orgService.Endpoint.Binding = new CustomBinding("CustomBinding_IOrganizationService");
```

The string passed to the custom binding is just the name taken from the config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <customBinding>
      <binding name="CustomBinding_IOrganizationService">
        ....
```

Edit: I discovered later on that changing the binding was not necessary. The error seemed to be being caused by an invalid security token. I changed the way I generated security tokens to use the `grant_type` of `password` and the error went away on its own.